# Python - Read TXT File lines --> Array

Tags: python, mysql, file-io

I need to open a text file with Python and read this Text file line by line to put it into an arrary. Later on I want to write every single content from that array into a database.
This is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

#importieren der Module
import MySQLdb
import sys
import re          # regex
import codecs      # utf8 support

# Datei file einlesen
names = []
fo = open("file.txt", "r")
print "Name of file:", fo.name
for line in fo:
    line = line.strip()

fo.close()
```

How can I do this ?
What is the right command to insert the text lines into an array ?

Comment: what does the textfile look like?

Comment: What is the right command to do what?

Comment: Like this: EYD 5567 NEW LINE EYD 9867 -- the right command to insert the text lines into an array.

Comment: Something like this. I do not have many experience with Python so far.

Comment: look up numpy.genfromtxt

Comment: Have you looked at the Python documentation for working with lists and arrays?  It's pretty straightforward stuff.

Comment: I already looked at it but as the STrings in the txt are "E YD565" it always only gives me the E and the program does not give an other index to every single line. EVerything is saved in names[0]. names[1] is empty.

Comment: you can pass it different delimiters, as well as a format to each line in your file, so it would really help if the text file is formatted as your say it is

Comment: It sounds like you also need to split the string.  Look at the documentation for splitting strings in Python.

Comment: Is your text file all one line? Cause shouldn't it just be as simple as putting "names.append(line)" in the for loop?

Comment: No. Every number is in a different line and there is also a space between the "E" and the number behind ("E YD6567" for example). It would also be possible do copy the datas directly from one database to the other one with mysql commands to get what I want.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, your text file looks something like this:

E YD6567
E YD9876
E YD9867
etc...

And you wish to remove the "E " and just store the "YD####" in a list. Your loop will look like this:

```
for line in fo:
    names.append(line.replace('E ', '')
```

The "append" function adds an item to a list. The "replace" function replaces whatever part of the string you specify with whatever else you specify (in this case, replacing "E " with nothing, effectively removing it from the string).

If you would like to store the full line (including "E "), it's as simple as:

```
for line in fo:
    names.append(line)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
lines = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

This should give you a list of all the lines in your code. This assumes that your text file is multi-lined and does not contain all of the text on a single line. If the text IS on a single line you can use this code to create a list of the lines.

```
splitOn = '\n'
fd = open('file.txt', 'r')
lines = fd.read().split(splitOn)
```

You can change splitOn to be any character you want to split the string on if there is some other symbol marking the end of lines instead of the newline character.